# htaccess language detection with redirect loop

Tags: .htaccess, loops, redirect

Ive been searching here, but no topic unfortunately helped me. Can someone explain me, why Im getting redirect loop?

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} (cs|sk) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain/cs/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} !(cs|sk) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Also I skip language detection via parameter fl in url adress, when user change language via navigation. 
Redirect loop is on http://domain/ and also when I change language and Ive got fl parameter in url adress and when I remove it from url adress and load domain again.

Thanks for all the advice.

Comment: There is different in accept language condition. There is exclamation mark !(cs|sk) when you arent from cs, sk. First redirect rule is for cs, sk

Comment: I see. This is probably useless rewrite rule. It was meaned that if you arent from cs, sk, you will be redirect to base url http//domain/

Comment: Removing 2nd rule probably helped on http/domain/, thank you, but still when I change language via navigation, so I am on http//domain/?fl=1 and remove ?fl=1 I get redirect loop.

Comment: You must be having more rules in this htaccess then or some other htaccess

Comment: Ive got, but complete same as those two rewrite rule, but for another domains. Production, devel and local.

Comment: Sorry I am blind. There is also redirect from no-www domain to www domain.